# How to categorize the products in their respective category?

Tags: cart, category-products

I want products like apple, orange etc in fruits category and fish in fresh fish category. How can i group them accordingly ? For example:

Fruits -> apple, orange.

Fresh Fish-> Bangude (Medium) fish, Kolathuru.

Please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to assign associate product to respective category from
   Products->Categories->Products in Category option. 
   ex: assign apple, orange to Fruits category
2. You can also set position for the product which displays on the frontend.